# Create a new column from Select statement then combining it with another Select statement in one procedure to return one data table

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to count data from a SQL table `Archive_Hits` and create a column `programStarts` that displays that data. Then I want to take the `programStarts` column and combine it with another Select statement to display one data table.

Here is my Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testing2] @startdate datetime, @enddate datetime
AS
BEGIN

SELECT Archive_Hits.inst_id, Count(Archive_Hits.type) AS programStarts 
FROM Archive_Hits 
WHERE Archive_Hits.type<>'New' AND Archive_Hits.accessed_on BETWEEN  cast ( @startdate as date)  and cast ( @enddate as date)
GROUP BY Archive_Hits.inst_id


SELECT email,product_market,install_code, programStarts
FROM (Archive_ProgUsers INNER JOIN Archive_Installations ON Archive_ProgUsers.id = Archive_Installations.user_id) 
INNER JOIN Archive_Hits AS hitsCount ON hitsCount.inst_id = Archive_Installations.id
ORDER BY programStarts DESC
```

Please note that I tried using UNION and UNION ALL methods, but that doesn't work if I don't have the same number of columns in each statement.

Also, The second select statement returns an error because it doesn't recognize the newly created column from the first Select statement.

==============================
Here is a sample result table result

[image]

Comment: You can add `NULL´ to the SELECT with fewer columns, to get the same number.

Comment: But the second SELECT is of course unaware of the first SELECT's programStarts column.

Comment: Make the 2nd query a sub-query that returns the one value as an expression/column. So, in place of a join, simply select the one value for that expression. And why not a left join to the 2nd table?

Comment: provide sample data ans desired output

Comment: @eshirvana Just updated my post with sample data.

Comment: @codernon you didn't share your desired output yet but  my answer still should be fine

Comment: @eshirvana I think I know what you mean. I attached a sample result table.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide sample data but I think this is what you need:

```
SELECT
    email,
    product_market,
    install_code,
    Count(case when hitsCount.type <> 'New' and hitsCount.accessed_on BETWEEN cast(@startdate as date) and cast(@enddate as date) then 1 end) over (partition by inst_id) as programStarts
FROM Archive_ProgUsers
INNER JOIN Archive_Installations ON Archive_ProgUsers.id = Archive_Installations.user_id
INNER JOIN Archive_Hits AS hitsCount ON hitsCount.inst_id = Archive_Installations.id
ORDER BY programStarts DESC
```

ok then you need this instead:

```
SELECT
    email,
    product_market,
    install_code,
    programStarts
FROM Archive_ProgUsers
INNER JOIN Archive_Installations ON Archive_ProgUsers.id = Archive_Installations.user_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT inst_id 
        , Count(case when hitsCount.type <> 'New' and hitsCount.accessed_on BETWEEN cast(@startdate as date) and cast(@enddate as date) then 1 end) as programStarts
    From Archive_Hits
    GROUP BY Archive_Hits.inst_id 
) AS hitsCount ON hitsCount.inst_id = Archive_Installations.id
ORDER BY programStarts DESC
```

Comment: your answers works, it looks like it's giving me an accurate number for ```programStarts``` . However, It also keeps repeating the same rows for the same user.

Comment: @codernon hmmm... thens ee the second solution

Comment: the second query worked!! 

You are the best!!!

Thank you!

Comment: @codernon you are welcome